# HttpCookie vs Response.Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, cookies

Hello fellow developers,

I'm a little new to working with cookies in ASP.NET and I apologize if this is a basic question. So I have the following code in my web.config that I was kind of playing around with to get an understanding of cookies.

```
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

Now here is my question. I created a cookie in two ways (which I needed to secure).

One way I secured it was with this code-

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
        cookie.Secure = true; // secure the cookie
        cookie["username"] = txtEmail.Text;

        if (txtEmail.Text != "")
        {
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

Now when I used this code to create it, I got the UserInfo cookie to be secured in this way was well.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["userName"] = txtEmail.Text;
}
```

Now here is my question. Why does using "Response.Cookies" default to using the settings in the web.config? How come when I create a cookie using HttpCookie I have to secure it by setting it to true in the CS code? My best guess was that since I'm creating an instance of HttpCookie, that is why but I wanted further direction on this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this setting is really needed? `Secure` is false by default, yes, but [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) suggests that all cookies are transmitted over SSL if web.config says so, unless explicitly overridden in the code. So basically even though `Secure` is false initially, as long as you do not explicitly run `Secure = false` you should be fine.

Comment: @Andrei Interesting. I'm not sure why but when I created the cookie using HttpCookie, "Secure" wasn't showing up as true. I thought maybe creating the cookie through the HttpCookie might be the reason since I'm instantiating it but I'm not sure whether that is the case.

Comment: Exactly, it won't be true, default value is false. But the key is as long as your code does not set `false` explicitly, cookie will be secure because web.config says so. Implementation of `HttpCookie` might be detecting explicit overrides some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does using "Response.Cookies" default to using the settings in the
>   web.config?

The simple/direct answer is this is by design.

Assuming the cookie doesn't existing when you call

```
Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["userName"] = txtEmail.Text;
```

The cookie is created for you and assigned the value but is given the defaults that you specified in:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>
```

However, if you were to instantiated as you already pointed out and add it to the collection, it will use those manually set values, which in the case of a `new HttpCookie`, the `Secure` property default value is false;

As specified in the Cookies Collection [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524757(v=vs.90).aspx)

You can get up close and personal with the code for [HttpCookieCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,5168357d8d389e38) as well to see more of the "why".